# Rename: [paper-mario-ttyd] -> [paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-rename-request

Title pretty much says it all: [paper-mario-ttyd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-mario-ttyd) should be renamed to [paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door).

The new tag name is 34 characters long, just below the limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a good idea. Done.